# how to restrict scrolling for +ve part in cpxygraph

Tags: iphone, graph, core-plot

I am new to core plot SDK, implemented core plot in my app. i need to restrict -ve part of graph. i.e always i will have +ve values for graph((1,1),(10,15),(20,15)).i need horizontal , vertical scrolling for +ve part only.So i want to restrict remaining 3 parts of graph. I tried in all ways help less, so posted here. if any one already done with this type requirement, please help me ASAP.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to restrict the scrolling ranges is to set the `globalXRange` and `globalYRange` properties on your plot space. If you want more control, you can use a plot space delegate. CPTestApp (the Mac version) demonstrates both techniques.